# positioning background image with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, background-size

I am building a Wordpress site.  On the homepage, I am trying to position a ball without affecting the other divs under the slider, which the theme maker has given the same class name.  What I want to do is make the ball small and place under the writing.  The theme does not allow me to assign a class to that image.  This is what I've tried but it affects the other images in that row. Could someone help me please?  I am thinking I may be able to use first child but not sure.  Thanks!

```
.cg-strip .cg-strip-bg {

  background-size: contain !important;
 background-position-y: 90%;
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div class="cg-strip-bg " style="background:url(http://adasportsandrackets.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ada-460-mole150x146hp.png) no-repeat center bottom / 80%!important; "></div>
```

Note!! don't use: `background-image:` but `background:`
with all this stuff:

```
url(blabla.png) no-repeat center bottom / 80%!important
```

80% is the size, might be a bit too much below your text, but you're free to fix till you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! The theme uses shortcodes. I added the bg image and it's keeping the ball at the top of the div-there is a height of 132px being applied. My CSS: `.yellow-ball {
background-image: url("http://adasportsandrackets.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ada-460-mole150x146hp.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}` and this is the theme backend: `[cg_content_strip custom_content_css="yellow-ball" height="402px" width="80%" bg="#1e73be" valign="top" halign="center" text_align="center" color="light" animation="fadeIn" text_fade_out="no" bg_img_type="simple"]`